# What is the need for Repository workspace in RTC?

Tags: rtc

When I have to get the code from ALM, I create a new repository workspace and then create the sandbox.

Why there is a need to create repository workspace?

Why cant I directly take the code from stream?

Comment: Don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer for this older question.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to modify and check-in changes to these files...

The Jazz source control in RTC relies on the repository workspace to track your changes.  This is your own private version of the stream on the Jazz server, and when you check-in your sandbox changes are pushed here from your Eclipse workspace.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in "[Working with repository workspaces](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.concert.dotnet.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_working_with_repository_workspaces.html)"

A repository workspace is a private development area where you can keep your work and those contributions that are shared by your team members.
**Your work is private to the workspace until you decide to deliver it to a team flow target such as a shared stream**.

> Setting up your repository workspaces with the proper contents and flow targets is the first step toward making your contributions to the team's efforts.

That is why there is an intermediate repo between the stream and your sandbox:

[image: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS4R3B_2.0.0/com.ibm.team.concert.tutorial.doc/images/scm-flows01.gif]
<sup>source: [Lesson 6: Source control](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4R3B_2.0.0/com.ibm.team.concert.tutorial.doc/topics/tut_rtc_scm.html)</sup>

You can read more about the "[relationships between Streams, Repository Workspaces, Components and Sandboxes.](http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-jazz/)":

[image: http://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-providers/maven-scm-provider-jazz/images/WorkspaceWithStream.png]

> A developer will deliver their changes to the flow targets defined for their Repository Workspace.
>   The corresponding action for a Snapshot is the promote operation. Another developer will accept those changes when they are ready too.